# Restart from stage with docker container runs on different node

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've 5 nodes and labelled them say `DockerNodes` and has pipeline code which is targeted to run against that label -

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            label "DockerNodes"
            image "<image-path>"
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage("Stage - I") {
            steps {
                script {
                    println "In stage I"
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Stage - II") {
            steps {
                script {
                    println "In stage II"
                    error "Failing intentionally"
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Stage - III") {
            steps {
                script {
                    println "In stage III"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When triggered a build, it runs on node say `A` of `DockerNodes` label and this fails at Stage-II(which I had done for testing)

When this failed build is restarted from failed stage, it starts running but not on node `A` but on some other node say `B` which is not intended for restart from stage.

Can you please help how I can achieve restart from stage to work on same node as of previous build's node?